Audio Alert addition in yolov8 model
how to add a audio alert like 'pothole ahead' in yolov8 model when pothole is detected
i was able to do real time detection but not able to add an alert audio in it when pothole is detected
the code i used for real time detection is
    import cv2
    from ultralytics import YOLO

    model = YOLO('D:/best.pt')

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # 0 for default webcam

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
             break

        results = model(frame)

        annotated_frame = results[0].plot()  

        cv2.imshow('YOLOv8 Real-Time Detection', annotated_frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

